# Exporting .blend to .obj with replicated geometry (front and back faces)

Tags: faces

How can I export a `.blend` model as an `.obj` model with double sided faces?

How can I export certain submodels of a `.blend` model as an `.obj` model for which only these submodels have double sided faces?

Concrete: I have a `.blend` model of a windmill consisting of two submodels: the building and the blades. Both submodels have normals that are set to be double sided in the Blender IDE. I assume this only affects the culling while rendering and not the actual geometry of the submodels themselves, because the face count remains the same. Furthermore, upon exporting to an `.obj` model, this does not result in the replication of geometry, whereas my goal is to replicate geometry (including the inversion of normals). And if possible only the faces of the blades (and not for the inside of the building).

Comment: Double Sided in the Object data tab in the Properties editor is Blender option for showing normals, it won't be supported in 3-rd party apps. Some of them will have analogue one, like some game engines but note that affects performance quite much (and you might be better to just model that geometry). If you want to add thickness to mesh use Solidify modifier

Comment: @MrZak I don't want to use some similar option in another program. I want to export the inside geometry as actual geometry in order to use front or back facing culling instead of no culling in a game engine.

Comment: As above, Double Sided is Blender-only option, it won't be exported. The only way if without adding geometry would be searching for alternative. To add actual geometry use Solidify modifier (the easiest way) and apply it; it will be actual geometry and will be exported as such.